# API Integration Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am new to integrating API's. I integrated a simple vehicle VIN decoder API into a form. Whenever a vehicle's VIN is entered into the first input and submit is selected, data regarding the vehicle should be displayed in the text area. The API is from NHTSA. Here is a link to it: [VIN Decoder](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/Home/Index/LanguageExamples)

This is the VIN I have been testing it with: WDBSK79F85F096997

It belongs to a 2005 Mercedes-Benz SL65

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VIN Decoder API Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
input {width: 200px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
  var val = $("#b12").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { format: "json", data: val},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#results").val(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
})
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <table align="center">
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="text" id="b12" placeholder="Enter VIN" name="b12" maxlength="100"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <textarea rows="15" cols="100" id="results" placeholder="Vehicle Data Presented Here"></textarea>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to why no data is showing up upon hitting submit.

Answer (score 0):

When you put your script inside `head` part, and your script depend on the `DOM` elements, you have to ensure that all `DOM` elements already loaded. There are multiple ways of doind that, one of them is to surround your script with `$(document.ready(function() { /*Your code is here*/ });`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VIN Decoder API Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
input {width: 200px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
    var val = $("#b12").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { format: "json", data: val},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#results").val(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
  })
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <table align="center">
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="text" id="b12" placeholder="Enter VIN" name="b12" maxlength="100"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <textarea rows="15" cols="100" id="results" placeholder="Vehicle Data Presented Here"></textarea>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your script in bottom of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>VIN Decoder API Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
input {width: 200px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <table align="center">
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="text" id="b12" placeholder="Enter VIN" name="b12" maxlength="100"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <textarea rows="15" cols="100" id="results" placeholder="Vehicle Data Presented Here"></textarea>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>

<script>
  $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
    var val = $("#b12").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { format: "json", data: val},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#results").val(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your click listener inside a `$(document).ready(function(){});`. The page is loading before your script is initialized. You can read more about it here http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/